# Sometimes, ConflatedBroadcastChannel fires recent value without any action

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.channels

In Google's official codelab about **advanced-coroutines-codelab** sample, they've used `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` to [watch a variable/object change](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/blob/b71b981f8354a92fb3ebda37eceb7461e783d0bf/advanced-coroutines-codelab/finished_code/src/main/java/com/example/android/advancedcoroutines/PlantListViewModel.kt#L91-L103).

I've used the same technique in one of my side projects, and when resuming the listening activity, sometimes `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` fires it's recent value, causing the execution of `flatMapLatest` body without any change.

I think this is happening while the system collects the garbage since I can reproduce this issue by calling `System.gc()` from another activity.

[image: issue]

Here's the code

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        val tvCount = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_count)

        viewModel.count.observe(this, Observer {
            tvCount.text = it
            Toast.makeText(this, "Incremented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        })

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.b_inc).setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.increment()
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.b_detail).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java))
        }

    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        val TAG = MainViewModel::class.java.simpleName
    }

    class IncrementRequest

    private var tempCount = 0
    private val requestChannel = ConflatedBroadcastChannel<IncrementRequest>()

    val count = requestChannel
        .asFlow()
        .flatMapLatest {
            tempCount++
            Log.d(TAG, "Incrementing number to $tempCount")
            flowOf("Number is $tempCount")
        }
        .asLiveData()

    fun increment() {
        requestChannel.offer(IncrementRequest())
    }
}
```

**DetailActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.b_gc)


        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() {
                button.isEnabled = true
                button.text = "CALL SYSTEM.GC() AND CLOSE ACTIVITY"
            }

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                button.text = "${TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)} second(s)"
            }
        }

        button.setOnClickListener {
            System.gc()
            finish()
        }

        timer.start()

    }
}
```

Here's the full source code : 
[CoroutinesFlowTest.zip](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/kotlin-coroutines/files/4558330/CoroutinesFlowTest.zip)

- Why is this happening?
- What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you need `.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)`?

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [official response](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1980#issuecomment-625729081), (The simple and straightforward solution)

> The problem here is that you are trying to use
>   `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` for events, while it is designed to
>   represent current state as shown in the codelab. Every time the
>   downstream `LiveData` is reactivated it receives the most recent state
>   and performs the incrementing action. Don't use
>   `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` for events.
>
> To fix it, you can replace `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` with
>   `BroadcastChannel<IncrementRequest>(1)` (non-conflated channel, which is
>   Ok for events to use) and it'll work as you expect it too.

Comment: You can just listen for `onSend` in your ConflatedBroadcastChannel, and filter by that.

Comment: Without using live data


```
val count = requestChannel
        .asFlow()
        .flatMapLatest {
            tempCount++
            Log.d(TAG, "Incrementing number to $tempCount")
            flowOf("Number is $tempCount")
        }
```
Use Flow and Coroutine


```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.count.collect {
                tvCount.text = it
                
            }
        }

```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [answer of Kiskae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61526635/10971172):

This might not be your case, but you can try to use `BroadcastChannel(1).asFlow().conflate` on a receiver side, but in my case it led to a bug where the code on a receiver side didn't get triggered sometimes (I think because [conflate](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/conflate.html) works in a separate coroutine or something).

Or you can use a custom version of stateless ConflatedBroadcastChannel (found [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1756)).

```
class StatelessBroadcastChannel<T> constructor(
    private val broadcast: BroadcastChannel<T> = ConflatedBroadcastChannel()
) : BroadcastChannel<T> by broadcast {

    override fun openSubscription(): ReceiveChannel<T> = broadcast
        .openSubscription()
        .apply { poll() }

}
```

Comment: Is this a valid solution, or a buggy one?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky StatelessBroadcastChannel is the solution that worked for me, I haven't noticed any bugs yet. I wouldn't say that `asFlow().conflate` is a "buggy" solution as well, it' just I guess in my case it wasn't a suitable solution. You can see a bit more info about it in the attached link

Comment: Channel is a non-blocking primitive for communication between a sender (via SendChannel) and a receiver (via ReceiveChannel).  Does `asFlow().conflate` meet this interface?

Comment: `asFlow` represents the channel as a flow (hot), and `conflate` conflates flow emissions via conflated channel and runs collector in a separate coroutine so that emitter never suspends. Also we're talking about BroadcastChannel here, I edited my answer to be more clear about that, and BroadcastChannel is "a non-blocking primitive for communication between the sender and multiple receivers", so, yes (considering the fact that we use Flow, not ReceiveChannel, to receive values)

Answer (score 2):

On Coroutine 1.4.2 and Kotlin 1.4.31

Without using live data

```
private var tempCount = 0
private val requestChannel = BroadcastChannel<IncrementRequest>(Channel.CONFLATED)

val count = requestChannel
        .asFlow()
        .flatMapLatest {
            tempCount++
            Log.d(TAG, "Incrementing number to $tempCount")
            flowOf("Number is $tempCount")
        }
```

Use Flow and Coroutine

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
     viewModel.count.collect {
          tvCount.text = it
          Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Incremented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Without using BroadcastChannel

```
private var tempCount = 0
    private val requestChannel = MutableStateFlow("")

    val count: StateFlow<String> = requestChannel
    
    fun increment() {
        tempCount += 1
        requestChannel.value = "Number is $tempCount"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very simple, `ViewModels` can persist outside of the lifecycle of `Activities`. By moving to another activity and garbagecollecting you're disposing of the original `MainActivity` but keeping the original `MainViewModel`.

Then when you return from `DetailActivity` it recreates `MainActivity` but reuses the viewmodel, which still has the broadcastchannel with a last known value, triggering the callback when `count.observe` is called.

If you add logging to observe the `onCreate` and `onDestroy` methods of the activity you should see the lifecycle getting advanced, while the viewmodel should only be created once.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for responding. So, how can I fix this ?

Comment: What'd suggest as a replacement for the `ConflatedBroadcastChannel` ?

Comment: The probably probably lies in the way you modelled your data, you have a queue of increment requests that holds onto its latest value. Since this mixes the purposes of displaying the current count and making a toast that an increment has happened you run into the current issue.